# what's the best way to add a class to the div with a class of post every 4 seconds using jquery?

Tags: jquery

what's the best way to add a class to the div with a class of post every 4 seconds using jquery?

```
<div class="34 post">
<img width="311" height="417" src="#" class="#" alt="newspapers" />
<h2><a href="#">Headline News Part 2</a></h2>
<p>testing new content</p>
</div>

<div class="9 post">
<img width="311" height="417" src="#" class="#" alt="newspapers" />
<h2><a href="#">Headline News Part 2</a></h2>
<p>testing new content</p>
</div>

<div class="6 post">
<img width="311" height="417" src="#" class="#" alt="newspapers" />
<h2><a href="#">Headline News Part 2</a></h2>
<p>testing new content</p>
</div>
```

so i want the first  to have a class of "display" then after 4 seconds, i want to remove the class on that one and add it to the second one. and then after 4 more seconds, remove it from the second and add it to the third. when it gets to the end it loops back around.

Comment: Hi Kegan, I've voted to close this as off topic since this question is not related to WordPress (see our [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq)). stackoverflow.com would probably be the more appropriate site. A mod will probably migrate this question over.

Comment: WOOPSIE. i just moved it over, ill delete it here

Comment: In the future, please just flag them for moderator attention. We can migrate off-topic questions for you. But since you've already opened one on SO, I'll close this one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var post_count = $('.post').length,
    current_index = 0;

setInterval(function(){

  $('.post').removeClass('display').eq(current_index).addClass('display');

  current_index++;

  if(current_index > post_count)
    current_index = 0; 

}, 4000);
```

Wrap it in a jQuery document.ready function :)